# Are $T_0$ topological quasigroups completely regular?

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, topological-groups, universal-algebra

In 1957 [H. Salzmann](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_lookup?title=Topologische%20projektive%20Ebenen&author=H..%20Salzmann&journal=Math.%20Z.&volume=67&pages=436-466&publication_year=1957) generalized to quasigroups but weakened the standard result that $T_0$ topological groups are completely regular. He was able to show that $T_0$ topological quasigroups are regular but left open the question if this could be improved to showing that they are completely regular. I haven't been able to find any discussion more recent than 1990 (when it is discussed by Hoffman and Strambach in a chapter of the book "Quasigroups and Loops: Theory and Applications" edited by Chein et. al.). At the time it was listed as a still open problem. That was nearly 30 years ago. Is the problem still open?

Comment: I don't recall exactly when Walter Taylor did his work on topological general algebras. If your references don't already tell you of his work, I recommend checking them out.  Gerhard "Or Use For Citation Search" Paseman, 2019.07.22.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Walter Taylor was my thesis advisor (back in the late 1980s/early 1990s). I looked at this very question back in the early 1990s, but made no fundamental progress. I have a couple of ideas for attacking it again, but don't want to waste my time if it has been solved in the meantime.

Comment: Keith Kearnes checks on MathOverflow occasionally. His adviser (and mine incidentally), Ralph McKenzie, was at Vanderbilt last I checked, and might know who has worked on this.  You could try emailing either of them.  Sorry I don't have more for you.  Writing up the approaches might have some benefit apart from solving this problem; you might consider doing that.  Gerhard "It's Been Awhile For Me" Paseman, 2019.07.22.

Comment: As far as I know this problem is still open. There are some partial recent results on the complete regularity of topological gyrogroups satisfying certain additional conditions, but the general case seems to be open.